# How to color individual boxes of an echarts boxplot based on function

Tags: echarts

How do I color each boxes individually in an echarts box-plot based on a function?

The following function works on a simple bar chart and colors the bars appropriately:

```js
series: [{
    data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
    type: 'bar',
    showBackground: true,
    itemStyle: {
        color: function(seriesIndex) {
            return ProfessionColor[seriesIndex.name.split("_", 1).toString()]
        },
    },
}]
```

However, it does not work on a box-plot:

```js
series: [{
        name: 'boxplot',
        type: 'boxplot',
        datasetIndex: 1,
        itemStyle: {
            color: function(seriesIndex) {
                return ProfessionColor[seriesIndex.name.split('_', 1)];
            }
        },
        encode: {
            tooltip: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'outlier',
        type: 'scatter',
        encode: {
            x: 1,
            y: 0
        },
        datasetIndex: 2
    }
]
```

If I provide color: "red" rather than a function all boxes are colored red.  This leads me to believe that it needs to happen in the transform.config which I can't find in the documents or tutorial.

[Echarts Box-Plot currently](https://codesandbox.io/s/box-plot-chart-20dlhc?file=/index.js:3754-4147)

The link is the complete charts in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, echarts only allows scripting (i.e., using a function for) *either* the line color -- option `itemStyle.borderColor` *or* the fill color -- option `itemStyle.color`.

The difference between the two appears to be made by the value of the internal property `BoxplotSeriesModel#visualDrawType`. It is now set to `"stroke"`, which means that `borderColor` *can* be set via a function.

Since you wanted to set the fill color, its value should be set to `"fill"`. I searched a way to change that property - it was rather difficult for echarts don't document an API for extensions. Still, navigating the source code I came up with this hacky solution:

```js
const BoxplotSeriesModel = echarts.ComponentModel.getClassesByMainType('series').find(cls=>cls.type==='series.boxplot');
const BoxplotSeriesModelFill = function(...args){
    const _this = new BoxplotSeriesModel(...args);
    _this.visualDrawType = 'fill';
    return _this;
}
BoxplotSeriesModelFill.type = BoxplotSeriesModel.type;
echarts.ComponentModel.registerClass(BoxplotSeriesModelFill);
```

That's a "patch" to be applied at the beginning of your script, immediately after you have the `echarts` global defined.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/box-plot-chart-forked-goqqf2?file=/index.js) a forked version of your code that uses that patch. The only other change I made was to set a `borderColor` (can now only be a fixed value) to black.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to see how to apply this to the `TW5-Echarts` version I am using or live with only being able to set borderColor.  I added the info to my bug/feature issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will not get you all the way, but if you add `colorBy: "data"` to your `options` and remove the `itemStyle`, it will look like this:
[image: boxplot colored by data]

Comment: Thanks, sadly this utilizes the default palette and I wanted to color based on profession colors from the game.  However, it did prompt me to forgo setting the color and trying `itemStyle.borderColor` which worked.

I filed a bug report on `itemStyle.color` not handling the function value properly.